# Override {} placeholders in python string format method

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to use python `format` method to do format my placeholder in a string.

The issue is the string contains *`{}`* internally and the string method is unable to resolve it.

```
my_value='v'
'{"k":"{value}"}'.format(value=my_value)    # This results in error due to outside {}
# Desired Output '{"k":"v"}'
```

How would I resolve this ?

- I can convert this to json and then substitute but I prefer if the string `format` can do it

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to override something, you can just escape the curly brackets by doubling them, as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for the format string syntax:

> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`.

```
>>> '{{"k":"{value}"}}'.format(value=my_value)
'{"k":"v"}'
```

This equally applies for formatted string literals if you plan on using them at some point:

```
>>> f'{{"k": "{my_value}"}}'
'{"k": "v"}'
```